# pandas series round down median and mean values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mean, series, median

I have a `series`,

```
s = pd.Series([1.115,2.337,3.225])
s.mean()

2.2256666666666667
```

I am wondering how to round the `mean()` and `median()` values, so that if the number at the 3rd decimal place is 5, it should round down, so the result should be `2.22` instead of `2.2256666666666667`.

Comment: why do you want to round? for print purposes? You can use pandas settings for this. Or do you want to output rounded values? Did you make any effort to look this up? It's the basics of python.

Comment: @AntonvBR to output rounded values

Comment: Then you could just use Python's round function: `round(s.mean(), 2)`... wait sorry you want to round it down? ... hmmm I guess: `import math` and `math.floor(s.mean()*100)/100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) will round to [*Nearest Even*](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF):

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1.115,2.337,3.225])
>>> s.mean()
2.2256666666666667
>>> np.around(s.mean(), decimals=4)
2.2257
>>> np.around(s.mean(), decimals=3)
2.226
>>> np.around(s.mean(), decimals=2)
2.23
```

...but:

> if the number at the 3rd decimal place is 5, it should round down [...] should be 2.22 instead of 2.2256666666666667.

This is not just rounding; you get 2.22 only if you truncate to 3 decimal places and then round to two:

```
>>> (np.trunc([s.mean() * 1000.]) / 1000.)[0]
2.225
>>> (np.around(np.trunc([s.mean() * 1000.]) / 1000., decimals=2))[0]
2.22
```